# The periodic condition is added to the differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation

$$
\frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)} \frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \phi^2}=-m^2
$$

with b.c.

$$
\Phi(\phi+2 \pi)=\Phi(\phi)
$$

it is easy to solve by wolfram

```
eq1 = D[Phi[phi], {phi, 2}]/Phi[phi];
sol1 = DSolve[eq1 == -m^2, Phi[phi], phi];
```

out is `{{Phi[phi] -> C[1] Cos[m phi] + C[2] Sin[m phi]}}`

---

In *QUANTUM CHEMISTRY* by McQuarrie(https://libgen.unblockit.cat/libraryp2/main/0FAA97ECA7C67AEAE6D4DD67E0217420)

$$
\Phi(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad \text { and } \quad \Phi(\phi)=A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}
$$

periodicity condition

$$
\Phi(\phi+2 \pi)=\Phi(\phi)
$$

so
$$
\begin{gathered}
A_m e^{i m(\phi+2 \pi)}=A_m e^{i m \phi} \\
A_{-m} e^{-i m(\phi+2 \pi)}=A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}
\end{gathered}
$$

by all of above can get

$$
e^{\pm i 2 \pi m}=1
$$

so

$$
m=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots
$$

finally

$$
\Phi_m(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad m=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots
$$

the periodicity condition $\Phi(\phi+2 \pi)=\Phi(\phi)$,How do I add periodicity conditions to my code?

---

In general *mathematical physics equations*,can be get this
$$
\Phi(\phi)=A_m \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} m \phi}+A_{-m} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} m \phi} \quad(m=0,1,2 \cdots)
$$

Comment: "by hand can get this $
\Phi(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad \text { and } \quad \Phi(\phi)=A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}
$"  How do you get this? As shown in Nasser's answer the general solution is $A_m e^{i m \phi} +A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}$

Comment: @xzczd you can download this book in https://libgen.unblockit.cat/libraryp2/main/0FAA97ECA7C67AEAE6D4DD67E0217420 ,page 270~271

Comment: Aha, Quantum Chemistry textbook, then it's not surprising to find unrigorous deduction. (And it's not even a deduction actually, the textbook simply claim the solution is $\Phi(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad \text { and } \quad \Phi(\phi)=A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}$. )

Comment: @xzczd  it seem to be dealt with in the general mathematical and physical methods books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change constants.

```
ClearAll[Phi, phi, m];
eq1 = D[Phi[phi], {phi, 2}]/Phi[phi];
sol = Phi[phi] /. First@DSolve[eq1 == -m^2, Phi[phi], phi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = TrigToExp[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the idea is to collect on the exponential terms

```
sol = Collect[sol, {E^(-I m phi), E^(I m phi)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We are free now to rename the constants (even if they are complex, it does not matter)

```
sol = sol /. {C[1]/2 - (I C[2])/2 -> A0, C[1]/2 + (I C[2])/2 -> A1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is what book says

$$
\Phi_m(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad m=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots
$$

**Update**

Answer the comment below. If the book meant to show the negative side also, then this can be done by expanding each term of the solution using `FourierSeries` and then applying `TrigToExp` on each term and collecting.

For example for `n=2` applied on `Cos[m phi]` gives

```
tab1 = Table[FourierSeries[Cos[m*phi], phi, n], {n, 0, 2}]
tab1 = Map[TrigToExp[#] &, tab1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then need to do the same for `Sin[ m phi]` and add and simplify. This will give answer for infinite terms as shown in book.

I do not have the time to write this fully now. If someone wants to do it, they are welcome to.

I read it as just they wanted to rewrite the solution are sum of only 2 complex exponentials instead of two trig functions. But I could be wrong on this.

Comment: This isn't complete, the condition $m=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$ hasn't been deduced.

Comment: Which is what book says?

you can down this book  in https://libgen.unblockit.cat/libraryp2/main/0FAA97ECA7C67AEAE6D4DD67E0217420 page 270~271

Comment: you seem forget this Φ(ϕ+2π)=Φ(ϕ)

Comment: @xzczd I did not look at it as they wanted the Fourier series expansion of the solution. But may be that is why wanted. Applying FourierSeries on each term of the solution should give the negative and positive terms. But I do not have time to code it now. Please feel free to post your answer on this as needed.

Comment: OK, I've posted a complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the deduction in *Quantum chemistry* by *McQuarrie* is not rigorous (if we don't call it incorrect). As shown in Nasser's answer, the general solution (when no b.c. is imposed) is

```
generalsol[phi_] = 
 With[{ϕ = Phi[phi]}, 
  Collect[DSolveValue[{D[ϕ, {phi, 2}]/ϕ == -m^2}, ϕ, phi] // 
     TrigToExp, E^_, Simplify] /. {C[1] - I C[2] -> 2 Subscript[A, "m"], 
    C[1] + I C[2] -> 2 Subscript[A, -"m"]}]

(* E^(-I m phi) Subscript[A, -"m"] + E^(I m phi) Subscript[A, "m"] *)
```

which is **not** the separate

$$
\Phi(\phi)=A_m e^{i m \phi} \quad \text { and } \quad \Phi(\phi)=A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi}
$$

Then what's the rigorous way to deduce the desired solution? To deduce it, we need to be aware of the following facts:

1. Though often written as a single $Φ(ϕ+2π)=Φ(ϕ)$ in various materials, when we say periodic boundary condition (b.c.) is imposed, *usually* it means we're imposing $Φ(ϕ+2π)=Φ(ϕ)$, $Φ'(ϕ+2π)=Φ'(ϕ)$, $Φ''(ϕ+2π)=Φ''(ϕ)$, …. The number of imposed periodic b.c.s depends on the order of differential equations.
2. `DSolve` (at least for now) is still a solver for generally valid solution i.e. the solutions that are only valid for $m=0,±1,±2,…$ i.e. $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be directly found by `DSolve`. (This behavior is similar to that of `Solve`. If you don't know what I mean, try `Solve[{a + 1 == 0, b == 0}, a]` and `Solve[{a + 1 == 0, b == 0}, a, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]`. )

OK, keep the facts in mind, let's start. With `generalsol` at hand, we just need to deduce $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. The ODE is of 2nd order, so we need 2 periodic b.c.s `Phi[0] == Phi[2 Pi], Phi'[0] == Phi'[2 Pi]`. Substitute the general solution into these and `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[{Phi'[0] == Phi'[2 Pi], Phi[0] == Phi[2 Pi]} /. Phi -> generalsol, 
  m] // FullSimplify
(*
(C[1] ∈ 
    Integers && (m == 1 + 2 C[1] || m == 2 C[1])) || (Subscript[A, -"m"] == 0 && 
   Subscript[A, "m"] == 0) || (Subscript[A, -"m"] == Subscript[A, "m"] && m == 0)
 *)
```

$$(c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land (m=1+2 c_1\lor m=2 c_1))\lor \left(A_{-\text{m}}=0\land A_{\text{m}}=0\right)\lor \left(A_{-\text{m}}=A_{\text{m}}\land m=0\right)$$

$A_{-\text{m}}=0\land A_{\text{m}}=0$ corresponds to the general trivial solution, which will be obtained if we substitute the 2 periodic b.c.s into `DSolve`:

```
phisol = DSolve[{D[Phi[phi], {phi, 2}]/Phi[phi] == -m^2, Phi[0] == Phi[2 Pi], 
   Phi'[0] == Phi'[2 Pi]}, Phi[phi], phi]

(* {{Phi[phi] -> 0}} *)
```

$(c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land (m=1+2 c_1\lor m=2 c_1))\lor  \left(A_{-\text{m}}=A_{\text{m}}\land m=0\right)$ is equivalent to $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. (Sadly I haven't found a way to make *Mathematica* prove this equivalence, but I think this is obvious enough. )

Alternatively, we can use `Solve` with `Reduce` option:

```
Solve[{Phi'[0] == Phi'[2 Pi], Phi[0] == Phi[2 Pi]} /. Phi -> generalsol, m, 
  Method -> Reduce] // Simplify
(*
{{m -> ConditionalExpression[2 C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
 {m -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 2 C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}}
 *)
```

The result is cleaner, but still, I haven't found a way to make *Mathematica* prove it's equivalent to $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: As you get `(C[1] \[Element] Integers && (m == 1 + 2 C[1] || m == 2 C[1])` ,it is actually the exact solution,But all the books I read are   m=0,-+1,-+2⋯

Comment: @我心永恒 Yes, and that's what I said in last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

There is [PeriodicBoundaryCondition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html). The syntax is a bit complicated:

```
PBC=PeriodicBoundaryCondition[Phi[phi],phi==2*Pi,phi|->phi-2*Pi];
```

This can be used with some solvers such as

```
{vals,funs}=NDEigensystem[{Phi''[phi],PBC},Phi[phi],{phi,0,2*Pi},10];
```

This will compute the first 10 eigenvalues and eigenfunctions

```
vals 
(* {0.,-1.00001,-1.00001,-4.00085,-4.00085,-9.00943,-9.00943,-16.0513,-16.0513,-25.1881} *)
```

This is a **numerical** result and contains numerical errors, the actual numbers are of course $$0,-1,-1,-4,-4,-9,-9,-16, \ldots$$
corresponding to $-m^2$ in OPs question.

To plot the eigenfunctions, use for example

```
Plot[{funs[[6]],funs[[7]]},{phi,0,2*Pi}]
```

which are linear combinations of $e^{3i\phi}$ and $e^{-3i\phi}$ in OPs question.

[image]